# Clear all data from Kendo viewmodel data container?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I'm trying to find a way to clear out all data from a data container inside a kendo viewmodel. My viewmodel looks something like this:

```
MyViewModel = kendo.observable ({
    dataContainer: {
        table1:[{
            data1: 'data',
            data2: 'otherdata'
        }],
        table2:[{
            data3: 'moredata',
            data4: 'evenmoreMydata'
        }],
    }
});
```

Is there a way to dynamically set all of the data points inside of the container labeled 'dataContainer' to either null or empty strings, while preserving the existing structure? Thanks!

**Edit:** What I want for the end result is to null out the data points within each table that dataContainer has, so it would look something like this:

```
MyViewModel = kendo.observable ({
    dataContainer: {
        table1:[{
            data1: null,
            data2: null
        }],
        table2:[{
            data3: null,
            data4: null
        }],
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will create an empty model;

```
myViewModel = kendo.observable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
function GetNewViewModal() {
  return new kendo.observable ({
    dataContainer: {
        table1:[{
            data1: null,
            data2: null
        }],
        table2:[{
            data3: null,
            data4: null
        }],
    } });
};

//If you want, assign this value in document ready function
var MyViewModel = GetNewViewModal();

function ClearMyModel() {
    MyViewModel = GetNewViewModal();
    //If you need to update view once again
    kendo.bind($("#div"), MyViewModel);
}
....

kendo.bind($("#div"), MyViewModel);
```